# How to change TCP congestion control algorithm on OpenBSD?

Tags: kernel, tcp, openbsd

On FreeBSD, I can change the TCP congestion control algorithm via `net.inet.tcp.cc.algorithm`.

On OpenBSD, there is no `net.inet.tcp.cc.algorithm` parameter.

So, here is the question：
How to change TCP congestion control algorithm on OpenBSD?

Answer (score 1):

I don’t believe this is readily possible.  I believe you’ll have to make custom changes to the kernel and recompile.  Outside of this, the closest thing is, likely, changing net.inet.tcp.rfc3390.